# Runtime of a programm that takes the square of a root

Tags: runtime-analysis

Assume $u(n)$ calculates $n^2$ in $n$ steps, thus is in $O(n)$, and $v(n)$ calculates the square root of $n$ in $\sqrt n$ steps, thus is in $O(\sqrt n)$.

What is the runtime of the program u(v(n))?

The argumentation in my solution is:

"We calculate the square root first, then we take it's square. $\sqrt n + \sqrt n = 2\sqrt n \rightarrow O(\sqrt n).$"

I don't understand that. Wouldn't it be actually $n + \sqrt n$?

Comment: You confused yourself by using too many variables named `n` when they are unrelated to each other. In the program `u(v(n))`, What is the input actually being passed into the program `u`?

Comment: The input is $\sqrt n$.

Comment: Then how many steps does $u$ takes for input $\sqrt{n}$? How many steps does $v$ takes for input $n$? Combining together, how many for $u(v(\_))$ on input $n$?

Comment: Ah, so if $u$ receives an $n$, it calculates it's square in $n$ steps, but now it's receiving an $\sqrt n$, hence it calculates it's square in $\sqrt n$ steps? Does this make sense? And $v$ takes $n$ and calculates its square root in $\sqrt n$ steps too, hence, $u(v(n))$ needs $\sqrt n + \sqrt n$ steps?

Comment: correct. congrats.

Comment: If you now know the answer to your question, would you like to write an answer to your own question?